# Could not find multidex.jar (com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-multidex

Could not find multidex.jar (com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.2/multidex

I have just installed latest version of Android Studio 3.1.3
When i tried to sync my project it shows failed to resolve : multidex

Also i tried https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.2/multidex this link which shows 404 error. Please help

Project Level :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply from: 'buildsystem/dependencies.gradle'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics:androiddevmetrics-plugin:0.5'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    ext {
        androidApplicationId = 'com.medikoe.connect'
        androidVersionCode = 23
        androidVersionName = "1.7.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testApplicationId = 'com.medikoe.test'
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
repositories {
    google()
}
```

App Level :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics'

configurations {
    devDebugCompile
    devSignedDebugCompile
    devPreReleaseCompile
    devReleaseCompile
    prodDebugCompile
    prodSignedDebugCompile
    prodPreReleaseCompile
    prodReleaseCompile
}


android {
    def globalConfiguration = rootProject.extensions.getByName("ext")

    compileSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidCompileSdkVersion")
    buildToolsVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidBuildToolsVersion")

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidMinSdkVersion")
        targetSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidTargetSdkVersion")
        versionCode globalConfiguration.getAt("androidVersionCode")
        applicationId globalConfiguration.getAt("androidApplicationId")
        testInstrumentationRunner globalConfiguration.getAt("testInstrumentationRunner")
        testApplicationId globalConfiguration.getAt("testApplicationId")

        multiDexEnabled true

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    dexOptions {

        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g"

    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }

    lintOptions {
        quiet true
        abortOnError false
        ignoreWarnings true
        disable 'InvalidPackage'            //Some libraries have issues with this.
        disable 'OldTargetApi'
        //Lint gives this warning but SDK 20 would be Android L Beta.
        disable 'IconDensities'             //For testing purpose. This is safe to remove.
        disable 'IconMissingDensityFolder'  //For testing purpose. This is safe to remove.
    }


    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('../buildsystem/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias '********'
            keyPassword '******'
        }

        signedDebug {
            storeFile file('../buildsystem/keystore_medikoe.jks')
            storePassword '*********'
            keyAlias '*********'
            keyPassword '**********'
        }
        preRelease {
            storeFile file('../buildsystem/keystore_medikoe.jks')
            storePassword '**********'
            keyAlias '******'
            keyPassword '********'
        }

        release {
            storeFile file('../buildsystem/keystore_medikoe.jks')
            storePassword '************'
            keyAlias '**********'
            keyPassword '************'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = false
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            // Enable pre-dexing to produce an APK that can be tested on
            // Android 5.0+ without the time-consuming DEX build processes.
            minSdkVersion 19
        }
        prod {
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the production version.
            minSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidMinSdkVersion")
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Connect-D"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "PRE_RELEASE", "false"
        }
        signedDebug {
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.signedDebug
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationIdSuffix ".signeddebug"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Connect-SD"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "PRE_RELEASE", "false"
        }
        preRelease {
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationIdSuffix ".prerelease"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Connect-PR"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "PRE_RELEASE", "true"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Medikoe Connect"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "PRE_RELEASE", "false"
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    def presentationDependencies = rootProject.ext.presentationDependencies
    def presentationTestDependencies = rootProject.ext.presentationTestDependencies
    def developmentDependencies = rootProject.ext.developmentDependencies

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27+'
    compile project(':Domain')

    devDebugCompile project(path: ':Data')
    devSignedDebugCompile project(path: ':Data')
    devPreReleaseCompile project(path: ':Data')
    devReleaseCompile project(path: ':Data')
    prodDebugCompile project(path: ':Data')
    prodSignedDebugCompile project(path: ':Data')
    prodPreReleaseCompile project(path: ':Data')
    prodReleaseCompile project(path: ':Data')

    devDebugCompile project(path: ':Infrastructure')
    devSignedDebugCompile project(path: ':Infrastructure')
    devPreReleaseCompile project(path: ':Infrastructure')
    devReleaseCompile project(path: ':Infrastructure')
    prodDebugCompile project(path: ':Infrastructure')
    prodSignedDebugCompile project(path: ':Infrastructure')
    prodPreReleaseCompile project(path: ':Infrastructure')
    prodReleaseCompile project(path: ':Infrastructure')

    //compile files('libs/date4j.jar')
    //compile files('libs/commons-collections4-4.1.jar')

    annotationProcessor presentationDependencies.daggerCompiler
    compile presentationDependencies.dagger
    compile presentationDependencies.rxJava
    compile presentationDependencies.rxAndroid
    provided presentationDependencies.javaxAnnotation
    //compile presentationDependencies.autoFactory
    compile presentationDependencies.butterKnife
    annotationProcessor presentationDependencies.butterKnifeCompiler

    compile presentationDependencies.designLibrary
    compile presentationDependencies.recyclerView
    compile presentationDependencies.cardView
    compile presentationDependencies.percent
    compile presentationDependencies.glide
    compile presentationDependencies.glideOkhttp3
    compile presentationDependencies.nineOldAndroids
    //compile presentationDependencies.ahBottomNav
    //compile presentationDependencies.lapismSearch
    //compile presentationDependencies.FragmentNavigator
    compile presentationDependencies.flexibleDivider
    compile presentationDependencies.materialDialogsCore
    compile presentationDependencies.materialFavoriteButton
    compile presentationDependencies.fancyButtons
    compile presentationDependencies.simpleRatingBar
    compile presentationDependencies.circularImageView
    compile presentationDependencies.waveLoadingView
    compile presentationDependencies.googleAutoFactory
    annotationProcessor presentationDependencies.googleAutoFactory
    compile presentationDependencies.playServicesPlaces
    compile presentationDependencies.playServicesLocation
    //compile presentationDependencies.tagGroup
    //compile presentationDependencies.expandableTextView
    //compile presentationDependencies.expandableLayout
    //compile presentationDependencies.touchImageView
    //compile presentationDependencies.sublimePicker
    compile presentationDependencies.rxpermissions
    compile presentationDependencies.rxActivityResult
    compile presentationDependencies.rxBinding
    compile presentationDependencies.rxPaparazzo
    compile presentationDependencies.rxBinding
    compile presentationDependencies.parcelerApi
    annotationProcessor presentationDependencies.parceler
    compile presentationDependencies.guava
    compile presentationDependencies.weekView
    compile presentationDependencies.jodaTime
    compile presentationDependencies.rxPaparazzo
    //compile presentationDependencies.collection
    compile presentationDependencies.RecyclerViewPager
    //compile presentationDependencies.googleAnalytics
    compile presentationDependencies.SpotsProgressDialog
    compile presentationDependencies.CustomActivityOnCrash

    compile presentationDependencies.multiDex
    compile presentationDependencies.SaripaarVersion
    //compile presentationDependencies.RazorPay
    compile presentationDependencies.Timecon
    compile presentationDependencies.ClansFab
    compile presentationDependencies.MPAndroidChart
    compile presentationDependencies.FragNav
    compile presentationDependencies.CircularFillableLoaders
    compile presentationDependencies.AvatarImageView
    compile presentationDependencies.AVLoadingIndicatorView
    compile presentationDependencies.Epoxy
    annotationProcessor presentationDependencies.EpoxyProcessor
    compile presentationDependencies.RelativeTimeTextView
    //compile presentationDependencies.AudioPlayerView
    compile presentationDependencies.EasyVideoPlayer
    compile presentationDependencies.ThreeTenAndroid
    //compile presentationDependencies.Steppers
    //compile presentationDependencies.RxAccountManager
    compile presentationDependencies.MaterialProgressBar
    compile presentationDependencies.FloatingView
//    compile presentationDependencies.HashtagView{
//        //Guava appears to be included explicitly in the list-services.jar
//        //Skip the redundant dependency
//        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
//    }
    compile('com.github.greenfrvr:hashtag-view:1.3.1@aar') {
        transitive = false
    }

    androidTestCompile presentationTestDependencies.mockito
    androidTestCompile presentationTestDependencies.dexmaker
    androidTestCompile presentationTestDependencies.dexmakerMockito
    androidTestCompile presentationTestDependencies.espresso
    androidTestCompile presentationTestDependencies.testingSupportLib
    androidTestCompile presentationTestDependencies.androidAnnotations
    androidTestCompile presentationTestDependencies.autoFactory
//    androidTestCompile presentationTestDependencies.guava

    //Development
    compile developmentDependencies.leakCanary
    compile developmentDependencies.DebugDatabase
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.4.1'
    compile('com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.4')
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.5.0'
    compile('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0')
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.0'
    compile 'com.myhexaville:smart-image-picker:1.0'
    compile 'com.github.blikoon:QRCodeScanner:0.1.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.IntruderShanky:Frisson:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.emrekose26:PinchZoom:-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.ablanco.zoomy:zoomy:1.0.0'
    compile 'xyz.danoz:recyclerviewfastscroller:0.1.3'
    compile 'com.irozon.sneaker:sneaker:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.kyanogen.signatureview:signature-view:1.2'
    compile 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.11.0'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.takusemba:multisnaprecyclerview:1.3.3'
    compile 'com.github.chahine:pageindicator:0.2.6'
    compile 'com.github.florent37:tutoshowcase:1.0.1'
    implementation 'io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:2.1.0'

    compile 'com.github.yeriomin:play-store-api:0.19'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'

    implementation 'com.github.antonKozyriatskyi:CircularProgressIndicator:1.0.5'}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: can u pls show me your `build.gradle` both in app level and project level? Maybe it's related to your version Android Studio Gradle tools, or your dependencies.

Comment: @YosiPramajaya please check

Comment: I am getting this error for 26.1.0 dependencies. Apparently they have been deleted from jcenter. They don't exist on the Google Maven repository either.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To me what worked was to move `google()` before `jcenter()` both on `buildscript` and on `allprojects`'s `repositories` element.

In your case:

```
repositories {
    maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    jcenter()
    // Add your other repositories here
}
```

I also tried the following and both work for me:

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    // Add your other repositories here
}
```

Comment: I guess Google system dependencies like multidex have to be loaded first to allow the build process to continue. Maybe the build is expecting to use multidex on the whole project once it becomes large enough just with the jcenter dependencies, but it crashes since it has not loaded multidex from google already

Answer (score 2):

Silly Mistake , Just make sure you are using

```
 maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

above

```
jcenter()
```

Thats the problem it was throwing Searched in the following locations: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.2/multidex

Comment: maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } can be replaced by google() in gradle 4.1+

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing using Android Studio 3.1.3, try to update your `build.gradle` dependencies and plugin as well to their latest version.

And move your repository `google()` to the `buildscript`.

You can try this:

Top-level build.gradle

```
apply from: 'buildsystem/dependencies.gradle'

buildscript {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
      mavenCentral()
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      google()
      //maven {
      //    url 'https://maven.google.com'
      //}
    }
    dependencies {
       //Update it to the latest version: 3.1.3
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3' 
       classpath 'com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics:androiddevmetrics-plugin:0.5'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
       classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
   ext {
     androidApplicationId = 'com.medikoe.connect'
     androidVersionCode = 23
     androidVersionName = "1.7.2"
     testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     testApplicationId = 'com.medikoe.test'
   }

   repositories {
     google()
     jcenter()
   }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
// Remove these lines
// repositories {
//    google()
// }
```

Some other tips:

For your app `build.gradle`, try to change `compile` to `implementation`, since it will be deprecated soon.

Comment: This answer has a reference to a third party analytics library 'com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics:androiddevmetrics-plugin:0.5'

Comment: Because I just copy and edit the snippet from the question.

Comment: My bad! Sorry, did not check that

Comment: @Arpit Can you show me what you have for `compile presentationDependencies.multiDex`?

Comment: multiDex   : "com.android.support:multidex:${multiDexVersion}"

whose version is 1.0.3

Comment: resolved it , i just need to make jcenter() below google() in project level gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

for any one who encounters this problem nowadays just put google() before any other repositories, both in buildscrript repositories and allprojects respository inside project level build.gradle file