# All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension Android Studio NDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

today i got a source project and i get this error when i'm tyring to sync

> All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension

My productflavors on module grade

```
    productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                ndk {
                    abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
                }
                versionCode = 1
            }
        }
```

I tried putting these codes above it

> flavorDimensions "default"
>
> > flavorDimensions "versionCode"

My build.gradle code:

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    configurations {
    implementation.exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:4.1.2'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.2'
    // telegraf
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
    implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    // implementation 'co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.12'
    // Download, Catch, Etc... Images
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    }
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig.applicationId = "ir.imodares.telegraf"
    defaultConfig.manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id : "639e4454-4b40-4b07-a35d-eb24786b14bf",
    // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
    onesignal_google_project_number: "1039318212221"]
    sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['./jni/']
    externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
    path "jni/Android.mk"
    }
    }
    dexOptions {
    jumboMode = true
    }
    lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    signingConfigs {
    debug {
    storeFile file("config/release.keystore")
    storePassword "PASS"
    keyAlias "KEY"
    keyPassword "PASS"
    v2SigningEnabled false
    }
    release {
    storeFile file("config/release.keystore")
    storePassword "PASS"
    keyAlias "KEY"
    keyPassword "PASS"
    v2SigningEnabled false
    }
    }
    buildTypes {
    debug {
    debuggable true
    jniDebuggable true
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
    debuggable false
    jniDebuggable false
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    foss {
    debuggable false
    jniDebuggable false
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    }
    defaultConfig.versionCode = 2000
    sourceSets.debug {
    manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    sourceSets.release {
    manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    sourceSets.foss {
    manifest.srcFile 'config/foss/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    productFlavors {
    armv7 {
    ndk {
    abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
    }
    versionCode = 1
    }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def abiVersion = variant.productFlavors.get(0).versionCode
    variant.mergedFlavor.versionCode = defaultConfig.versionCode * 10 + abiVersion
    }
    defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionName "3.18.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
    arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk", "APP_PLATFORM:=android-16"
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
    }
    }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[My Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjNPI.jpg)

[My Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIycW.jpg)

[My Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNeK5.jpg)

[My Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jLvt.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors.

You must explicitly name the flavor for **armv7** dimension if you declare more than one flavor. But here you don't need more than one:

```
flavorDimensions "single-dimension-name-does-not-matter"
productFlavors {
  armv7 {
    ndk {
      abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
    }
    versionCode = 1 + defaultConfig.versionCode * 10
  }
  all {
    versionCode = defaultConfig.versionCode * 10
  }
}
```

Now you will get 6 APKs:

- `telegraf-armv7-debug`,
- `telegraf-armv7-release`,
- `telegraf-armv7-foss`,
- `telegraf-all-debug`,
- `telegraf-all-release`,
- `telegraf-all-foss`

with appropriate **versionCode**s. You don't need to work with **applicationVariants** manually.

On the face of it, you actually don't need flavors at all to accomplish your task. You can use [splits](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split). And in this case you need the **applicationVariants** to set **versionCode** correctly ;)

Comment: thanks . i replaced the codes but now i get some other errors , my libraries can't load ... Failed to resolve: com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2
and etc ...

Comment: Most likely, this is a different problem. The **build.gradle** you posted refers to **multidex:1.0.1**. You probably upgraded to **1.0.2** because some dependency got upgraded, too. I hope https://stackoverflow.com/a/50794342/192373 will help you.

Comment: It's not only multi dex , all my dependecies have errors , i think 20 libraries

Comment: Do you think it's related to the flavors? If not, please open a separate question, and provide more info, e.g. which components require **com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2** (remind you, your project imports **com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1**)

Comment: worth noting that all flavors don't get built at the same time as of Android Studio v3.5. You will need to select the one you want to have build by going to `Build > Select Build Variant` and selecting the `Active Build Variant` drop-down in the popup.

Comment: @lasec0203 no, they are not built, and never were AFAICR. Today, AS does perform some optimization and doesn't waste time 'preparing' to build inactive flavors.